# What does "delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed" truly mean? And what is the goal of apt-utils then?

Tags: apt

I encounter a problem I'm asking GIS community of *StackExchange* about : [a *Docker* installation from a `postgis:postgis` image that doesn't install the command it should](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384181/missing-shp2pgsql-command-on-postgis-docker-installation-when-i-use-postgispos). The current workaround I have for it, executing an additional `apt-get install postgis` to make my missing commands appearing, is disturbing.

This is why, aside from this problem, I'm wondering about the goal of `apt-utils` package during installations.
Without it, I see the warning message coming :
*delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed.*

What does it mean ?
That the system is waiting a reboot or the service a reload to configure itself ?
What is the goal of the `apt-utils` package ? Should it be present in each installation ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/358950/229499 ... I don't think it has anything to do with your `postgis` problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The short version is that everything is fine, you can ignore the message, nothing extra needs to be done.

The message means that the package can’t be pre-configured before its installation, because `apt-extracttemplates` is missing. Nothing bad happens as a result, and the package does end up being configured correctly.

In more detail, when `apt-extracttemplates` (part of `apt-utils`) isn’t present, this is what happens:

- `apt` builds up the set of packages to be installed, removed, etc.;
- `dpkg` is invoked to perform the actual change;
- each package is extracted, and its maintainer scripts are run, including any configuration; in interactive mode, this can result in multiple questions being asked throughout installation.

When `apt-extracttemplates` *is* present, package configuration can instead be performed early in the `dpkg` run, before the packages are even extracted; this allows any questions to be asked ahead of time, and then installation can proceed without human intervention.

In a container context, installations are supposed to proceed in noninteractive mode anyway, so pre-extracting configuration templates offers no benefit and `apt-utils` isn’t useful. `apt-utils`’s purpose is described in [its package description](https://packages.debian.org/buster/apt-utils):

> This package contains some less used commandline utilities related to package management with APT.
>
> - `apt-extracttemplates` is used by `debconf` to prompt for configuration
>   questions before installation.
> - `apt-ftparchive` is used to create Packages and other index files
>   needed to publish an archive of Debian packages
> - `apt-sortpkgs` is a Packages/Sources file normalizer.